# Build Failed: Visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, build

When I try to compile my project on Visual Studio 2010 Professional I receive this error:

> Compile complete -- 1 errors, 0 warnings
>   Build started 15/08/2012 19:30:23.
>   ResolveAssemblyReferences:
>     A TargetFramework profile exclusion list will be generated.
>   CoreResGen:
>     "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\resgen.exe" /useSourcePath /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\mscorlib.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.Core.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.Data.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.Deployment.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.Drawing.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.Windows.Forms.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.Xml.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\TaoFramework\bin\Tao.FreeGlut.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\TaoFramework\bin\Tao.OpenGl.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\TaoFramework\bin\Tao.Platform.Windows.dll" /compile Form1.resx,obj\x86\Debug\WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.resources Properties\Resources.resx,obj\x86\Debug\WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.resources
>     Processing resource file "Form1.resx" into "obj\x86\Debug\WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.resources".
>     Processing resource file "Properties\Resources.resx" into "obj\x86\Debug\WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.resources".
>   GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
>   Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
>   CoreCompile:
>     C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /platform:x86 /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\mscorlib.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.Data.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.Deployment.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.Drawing.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.Windows.Forms.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.Xml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\TaoFramework\bin\Tao.FreeGlut.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\TaoFramework\bin\Tao.OpenGl.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\TaoFramework\bin\Tao.Platform.Windows.dll" /debug+ /debug:full /filealign:512 /optimize- /out:obj\x86\Debug\WindowsFormsApplication1.exe /resource:obj\x86\Debug\WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.resources /resource:obj\x86\Debug\WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.resources /target:winexe Form1.cs Form1.Designer.cs Program.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs Properties\Resources.Designer.cs Properties\Settings.Designer.cs "C:\Users\Antonino Saitta\AppData\Local\Temp.NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client.AssemblyAttributes.cs"

Build FAILED.

can someone help me telling me what the problem is?

Comment: Try changing the target framework to .NET Framework 4.0

Comment: Visual Studio has an Error Browser. Press Ctrl+W then E.

Comment: The part of the log youshow does not have the error in it, please display the part of the log with the actual error in it.

Comment: +1 @Jeff - I run into immediate compile issue with new class library projects because VS defaults to .NET Framework 4 Client Profile.  When I change to .NET Framework 4, everything is golden.

Comment: Great - should I add it as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I've founded solution!

```
this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
```

This was the error... I forgot to delete that line of code! ;)

Comment: Great, and +1 for sharing your solution!

Answer (score 0):

Usually (for me), creating a new .NET project makes the target framework default to .NET Framework 4.0 (Client Profile) - this can produce some errors (tried it myself). You can change it in the Project Options, to .NET Framework 4.0.

You can also make new projects use .NET Framework 4.0 right before you press Create, it should be at the top of the New Project window, if my memory serves me right.

Comment: At what stage does this occur?

Comment: Yes I know, but does this happen when you create a new project, too?